# Typescript how to check the type of an object with multiple types

Tags: typescript

I have the following code in typescript

```
Array.map((r: number | PointOptionsObject | [string, number | null] | null ) => {
                    if (r) {
                      ;`
                      ${r.phrase}:
                      <span> hello </span>
                      `
                    }
                  })
```

I am getting an error in typescript, `property phrase doesn't exist on type number` essentially the only data that I am using is of type PointOptionsObject which has the phrase property.. But I am forced to use this long declaration for each of the data items in the array's type because it is the type of the built in library. If I change my code to have

`if(typeof r !== "number")`

Then I get a new error `Property 'phrase' does not exist on type '[string, number | null]'`

And here is where I am stuck, I am not sure how to check the type of this and we cant using the built in `typeof` operator. How can I check that the value of r is only the PointOptionsObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate all invalid types by adding another type guard for arrays, using the built in array method `Array.isArray`:

```
type PointOptionsObject = {
  phrase: string;
}

type DataTypes = number | PointOptionsObject | [string, number | null] | null;

const result = [].map((r: DataTypes ) => {
  if (r && typeof r !== "number" && !Array.isArray(r)) {
    ;`
    ${r.phrase}:
    <span> hello </span>
    `
  }
})
```

Alternatively you could write your own type guard which checks for `PointOptionsObject` specifically. Extend this to cover all properties that the object actually has:

```
const isPointOptionsObject = (o: any): o is PointOptionsObject => {
  return o && o.hasOwnProperty("phrase") && typeof o.phrase === "string";
}
```

And use it like:

```
const result = [].map((r: DataTypes ) => {
  if (isPointOptionsObject(r)) {
    ;`
    ${r.phrase}:
    <span> hello </span>
    `
  }
})
```